# cannot get my strapi data from my next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to build a portfolio website with Next.js and Strapi, and I'm having a hard time getting the data from the about page onto the screen. I am getting the data in postman. Here is my code...

```
import {API_URL} from "../config";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

export default function AboutPage({about}) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <main className="container relative">
                <div className="p-4 md:p-12 md:w-3/4 mx-auto relative">
                    <section className="bg-brown text-white text-center md:text-left rounded-lg lg:flex p-12 md:p-20">
                        <img
                            src={about.image.url}
                            className="h-60 w-48 lg:w-64 lg:h-80 mx-auto md:mr-12"
                            alt={about.name} id="about-img"/>
                        <div className="text-lg flex flex-col justify-center">
                            <h1 className="mono text-xl my-8">Hi! My name is {" "}
                                <span>{about.name}</span>
                            </h1>
                            <div className="prose lg:prose-xl text-base">
                                {about.description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </main>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/abouts`)
    const about = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {about}
    }
}
```

I'm new to this, could someone please help me

Comment: Do you get any errors? If you log the `about` data to the console inside `getStaticProps` do you get the expected output in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

you should get props

```
import {API_URL} from "../config";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

export default function AboutPage({props}) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <main className="container relative">
                <div className="p-4 md:p-12 md:w-3/4 mx-auto relative">
                    <section className="bg-brown text-white text-center md:text-left rounded-lg lg:flex p-12 md:p-20">
                        <img
                            src={props.about.image.url}
                            className="h-60 w-48 lg:w-64 lg:h-80 mx-auto md:mr-12"
                            alt={props.about.name} id="about-img"/>
                        <div className="text-lg flex flex-col justify-center">
                            <h1 className="mono text-xl my-8">Hi! My name is {" "}
                                <span>{props.about.name}</span>
                            </h1>
                            <div className="prose lg:prose-xl text-base">
                                {props.about.description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </main>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/abouts`)
    const about = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {about}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working `TypeError: Cannot read property 'about' of undefined`

Comment: Same here, i get index.json with 
// 
pageProps
: 
{homepage: null}
homepage: null
__N_SSP: true
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?